# Casting URLConnection to HttpUrlConnection in Nashorn

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I've got some code:

```
var Base64 = java.util.Base64;
var URL = java.net.URL;
var HttpURLConnection = java.net.HttpURLConnection;
var connectionAddress = new URL("http://twitter.com/");
var httpConnection = Java.to(
        connectionAddress.openConnection(),
        Java.type("java.net.HttpURLConnection")
    );
```

this throws an exception:
TypeError: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://twitter.com/ is not an Object

anyone have any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Is this java code or javascript code? Why is `var` keyword there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Java.to` is used to convert a JavaScript object to a Java object. Currently it supports conversion to Java array types, as well as `java.util.List` and `java.util.Deque`. It can't be used to "cast" between Java types, and anyway, it's not a meaningful concept in a dynamic language. Your `openConnection()` invocation gave you back a Java object of type `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`, which sounds like something that is already a subclass of `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, so you should all be set just by writing

```
var httpConnection = connectionAddress.openConnection();
```

Comment: I've noticed that I can use the sun.net directly.
Only after I've read your comment it hit me that in dynamic languages casting has no sense :) Thanks for pointing it out. It is just like in Python duck-typing. If the method is there it will be invoked.